# Checkbox kind of fields with XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following piece of XSD:

```
<xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="mes:Request">
         <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="empId" type="xsd:string"/>
           <xsd:element name="empTaskId" type="xsd:int"/>
           <xsd:element name="empStateName" type="xsd:string"/>
           <xsd:element name="empTypeName" type="xsd:string"/>
           <xsd:element name="empActionName" type="xsd:string"/>
           <xsd:element name="empTransactionId" type="xsd:int"/>                               
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
```

What I want, is to allow only one field as mandatory from any of the fields listed into `<sequence>`. I tried using `<choice>` but it behaves like radio buttons; I want the functionality of check boxes (1 or more fields - multiple choice).

Can any one help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start moving into "validation logic" you hit the limitations of XML Schema. XML Schema can't do that so you either need to perform a basic validation with XML Schema in the lower layers of your app an in the upper layers reinforce the logic that XML Schema couldn't handle or [move to something with more expressive validation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron).

That aside, the best I can think of enforcing your requirements with XML schema is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:t="http://tempuri"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Demo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="6">
        <xsd:element name="empId" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="empTaskId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="empStateName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="empTypeName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="empActionName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="empTransactionId" type="xsd:int"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:unique name="unique1">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empId"/>
    </xsd:unique>
    <xsd:unique name="unique2">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empTaskId"/>
    </xsd:unique>
    <xsd:unique name="unique3">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empStateName"/>
    </xsd:unique>
    <xsd:unique name="unique4">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empTypeName"/>
    </xsd:unique>
    <xsd:unique name="unique5">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empActionName"/>
    </xsd:unique>
    <xsd:unique name="unique6">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="t:empTransactionId"/>
    </xsd:unique>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

You use the `<choice>` element to only select one type of element with `minOccurs="1"` so you can have at least one of it and `maxOccurs="6"` to have them all. But now you could select the same element more times so you have to restrict that and this is where `<unique>` comes into play.

But do be aware that this example is not without it's limitations, being that you can't restrict the order of the elements (i.e. reinforce the `<sequence>` restriction).